# Lazy page scrolling is not working , can't figure out the problem in the code

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, database

```
 <script>

   $(document).ready(function(){
     $.ajax({
       type:"GET",
       url:"fetch_home.php",
       data:{
         'offset':0,
         'limit':1
       },
       success:function(data){
         $('body').append(data);
       }
     });

   $(window).scroll(function(){
     if($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
       alert('at bottom'); 
       // i will place rest of the code here .
     }
   });

   });
      </script>
```

And here is the php section that links with the ajax -

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["limit"],$_POST["start"])){
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','user_data') or 
  die(mysqli_error());

$query = "SELECT * FROM `challenges` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT {$limit} 
OFFSET {$offset}";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
          echo '<p>'.$row["challenger_name"].'</p>';
   }
   mysqli_error($con);
 }

 ?>
```

I have no idea what exactly i do wrong inside it .
please help me out to figure out the things that i have did wrong inside it.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @Sfili_81 i am not getting any result on screen , it is blank.

Comment: So i'll suggest you to view in browser consolle if ajax get some value, and try to var_dump your database result

Comment: @Sfili_81 okay , let me see inside console

Comment: @Sfili_81 nothing on console too , is this the right way to do it ?

Comment: @Sfili_81 Why would the OP want to return JSON? He is just appending HTML to an existing HTML document.

Comment: @BenHillier yeah you're right, in this case it's not necessary, i'll remove the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call a variable `offset` in your javascript, but then look for `start` in your php code. Nothing will run, because it never enters the `if` statement.

Try this:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST["limit"],$_POST["offset"])){  //Change variable name here
        $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','user_data') or 
            die(mysqli_error());

        $query = "SELECT * FROM `challenges` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT {$limit} 
    OFFSET {$offset}";

        $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
              echo '<p>'.$row["challenger_name"].'</p>';
        }
        mysqli_error($con);
     }

 ?>
```